# How to make path that follows fill of existing path?

Tags: inkscape, path, stroke, fill

### Context

I bought a vector EPS image. I want to use my Brother Scan-n-Cut to draw it; this machine takes an SVG and draws a stroke along every path. When I imported the file into inkscape, it turned into a set of paths that are *filled* to make those lines.

What it looks like with the paths **filled** only:
[image: filled path]

What it looks like with the paths **stroked** only:
[image: stroked path]

Because of how the Brother Scan-n-Cut works, I want a path that looks, when stroked only, like the filled version above.

### The Question

How can I make paths that lie along the lines that appear when the existing paths are filled?

Comment: In illustrator there is a feature called "Convert stroke to path" you're looking for the opposite of what that does (to *undo* it) correct?

Comment: Yes, I think that's correct.

Comment: There's no built-in feature to reverse converted strokes, so unless somebody comes up with a plugin or something, you'd have to manually rework every line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

About the only option you have would be the extension known as [centerline-trace](https://github.com/fablabnbg/inkscape-centerline-trace), which also requires autotrace and inkscape helper. I had pursued this objective in the past and found this particular inkscape add-on, but was not able to make it work due to incorrect version application on my part.

I had then given up the task, perhaps resorting to manual editing, so I cannot lay claim to having the correctly functioning answer.

The description clearly indicates that it fits your requirements, but the implementation is unproven on my end.

[image: centerline trace poster]

You can see that changing parameters changes the results. For your example image, I suspect the results are attainable, if the extension will install and operate.